# Perl - need to store the column values into hash

Tags: perl, hash

I want to create a hash with column header as hash key and column values as hash values in Perl.

For example, if my csv file has the following data:

```
A,B,C,D,E 
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15 ...
```

I want to create a hash as follows:

```
A=> 1,6,11
B=>2,7,12
c=>3,8,13 ...
```

So that just by using the header name I can use that column values. 
Is there a way in PERL to do this? Please help me.

I was able to store required column values as array using the following script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( IN, "sample.csv" ) or die("Unable to open file");
my $wanted_column = "A";
my @cells;
my @colvalues;

my $header       = <IN>;
my @column_names = split( ",", $header );
my $extract_col  = 0;

for my $header_line (@column_names) {
    last if $header_line =~ m/$wanted_column/;
    $extract_col++;
}
while ( my $row = <IN> ) {
    last unless $row =~ /\S/;
    chomp $row;
    @cells = split( ",", $row );
    push( @colvalues, $cells[$extract_col] );
}
my $sizeofarray = scalar @colvalues;
print "Size of the coulmn= $sizeofarray";
```

But I want to do this to all my column.I guess Hash of arrays will be the best solution but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also: Are you sure you want headers -> columns? Because the example you give, you've got headers mapping to rows.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I want headers to columns. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) is a useful helper module for this sort of thing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my %combined;
open( my $input, "<", "sample.csv" ) or die("Unable to open file");
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );
my @headers = @{ $csv->getline($input) };

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
    for my $header (@headers) {
        push( @{ $combined{$header} }, shift(@$row) );
    }

}
print Dumper \%combined;
```

Since you requested without a module - you *can* use `split` but you need to bear in mind the limitations. `CSV` format allows for things like commas nested in quotes. `split` won't handle that case very well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %combined;
open( my $input, "<", "sample.csv" ) or die("Unable to open file");
my $line = <$input>;
chomp ( $line );
my @headers = split( ',', $line );

while (<$input>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split(',');
    for my $header (@headers) {
        push( @{ $combined{$header} }, shift(@row) );
    }

}
print Dumper \%combined;
```

Note: Both of these will effectively ignore any extra columns that don't have headers. (And will get confused by duplicate column names).

Comment: Is there any way without using any module? I should do it without using modules.

Comment: Yes. You can use `split` on `,`. Just bear in mind that `CSV` allows things like commas within quotes, which `split` won't handle. Edited with another example. But I would urge you to use the former if you can, it's less likely to break later.

Comment: Note that the above will ignore any extra columns without headers.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution by using `for` loop :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data; 
my @columns; 

open (my $fh, "<", "file.csv") or die "Can't open the file : ";

while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;
    my @list=split(',', $_);
    for (my $i=0; $i<=$#list; $i++)
    {
        if ($.==1)  # collect the columns, if its first line.
        {
            $columns[$i]=$list[$i];
        }
        else        #collect the data, if its not the first line. 
        {
            push @{$data{$columns[$i]}}, $list[$i];
        }
    }
}
foreach (@columns)
{
    local $"="\,";
    print "$_=>@{$data{$_}}\n";
}
```

Output will be like this :

```
A=>1,6,11
B=>2,7,12
C=>3,8,13
D=>4,9,14
E=>5,10,15
```